# Node.js endpoint ampersand is getting appended when making an ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I've the below code which I'm using to hit a node.js endpoint. However when it is getting hit, the endpoint URL appends an `&` to it like this,

```
http://localhost:3004/expenses/?q=&12/02/2014
```

Hence I'm not getting the desired result back.

Here is how my code looks like,

```
$('#myForm').on('submit', (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:3004/expenses/?q=',
        processData: false,
        data: $('#startDate').val(),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success:(data, status)=>{
            // alert(status);
        },
        error:()=>{
            alert('problem');
        }
    })
})
```

Can someone shed some light?

Comment: 1) Why not append that to the url yourself if you want `processData: false`?  2) Remove the contentType.  You are not putting json on the request body.

Comment: Otherwise, remove the `?q=`, remove the `processData` and `contentType`, and give it a `data:{ q: $('#startDate').val() }` and call it a day

Comment: Tried 1, 2 and the last comment, but had no luck. :(

Comment: All I need is, to get rid of `&` from => `?q=&12/02/2014` which is getting auto appended.

Comment: You removed the `data`, `contentType`, `processData` and changed the `url: 'http://localhost:3004/expenses/?q='+ $('#startDate').val()` and it did not work?

Comment: Yeah.. The last one does the trick!..

Comment: The issue is most likely related to the `processData: false` telling jQuery to not format the data for the request.  Given that it is a GET request, the data has to go in the query params.  And since your url already has a `?` in it, jQuery is probably expecting you to have formatted the data already as key value pairs, so it is just tacking it on with the `&` for it to work.

Comment: Got it @Taplar. I was wondering how it was getting appended. Can you please post this as answer. I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is most likely related to the `processData: false` telling jQuery to not format the data for the request, and the GET url already containing `?` in it.  Given that you are not giving the request json, I would suggest reducing your call to simplify the issue.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:3004/expenses/',
    data: { q: $('#startDate').val() },
    success:(data, status)=>{
        // alert(status);
    },
    error:()=>{
        alert('problem');
    }
});
```

If you do not give the `processData` in the options, it will convert the data you give it to a query param for the request.  Given that this is a GET request, it will generate the `?q=<value>` for you.  And as mentioned in the comments, you do not need `contentType: application/json` on the options as that is telling jQuery to put the content type on the request so the server knows you are sending it json in the body.  Which you are not, :)